# JIRA integration to my project

Tags: jira, jira-rest-api, ticket-system

How should I integrate JIRA to my software to be able to use it's ticket management?
I've gone through REST API documentation but not able to understand what exactly should I do.

Comment: This question is far too vague to be able to provide a useful answer.

Comment: basically I want to be able to fetch jira tickets and to be able to manipulate thm through my application.

Comment: You can use the REST API to get the information about the tickets, but you cant just manipulate them

Comment: @Runningriot I've successfully fetched the issues and the details related to each of them. Can't I store that data and use it to edit which will ultimately edit the data at jira server?

Comment: No, the tickets information is stored in a database. You can alter the database yourself but that isnt done through the jira API.

Comment: @Runningriot okay! Thanks a lot :)

Comment: Of course you can update issues via the JIRA REST API. Just look at the available PUT/POST resources.